# problems building rpm with scons

Tags: rpm, scons

i am a newbei in SCons and i am trying to build an rpm with SCons. This is the part that fails

```
rpm_env = Environment(tools=['default','packaging'])
rpm_env['RPM_BUILD_ROOT'] = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'test-rpm')

rpmDist = rpm_env.Package(
PACKAGEROOT = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'test-rpm'),
NAME='pmpb',
VERSION='1.2.3',
PACKAGEVERSION="1",
PACKAGETYPE='rpm',
DESCRIPTION = "Test",
SUMMARY = "test Sum",
LICENSE = "liscent",
X_RPM_GROUP="Application/pattern-matcher"
)
rpm_env = Environment(tools=['default','packaging'])
rpm_env['RPM_BUILD_ROOT'] = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'test-rpm')
```

when running the scons i get an error when creating the spec file

```
scons: *** [build/debug/applications/pattern_matching/pmpb-1.2.3.spec] AttributeError :      'File' object has no attribute 'PACKAGING_INSTALL_LOCATION'
```

can someone tell me what i am doing wrong
thanks

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://markmail.org/message/2wsc7krhdvhl52xg#query:+page:1+mid:s5by6u2vhoon6tmx+state:results

Comment: This one is the same answer, but might be easier to read: http://scons.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1272&dsMessageId=923380

Comment: i have read the links and they tell me to do a Tag on the file. i dont't realy know to what file to to the tag. the spec file is not generated yet. to whom do i need to do the tag?

Comment: Sorry to say that I really dont know. Maybe you could try sending an email to the SCons dev list: scons-users@scons.org or scons-dev@scons.org